# At level one, can you really never recover hit dice?

Tags: dnd-5e, healing, rests, hit-dice

I was reading a review of 5e game play [here](http://walkingmind.evilhat.com/2014/07/20/dd-5e-post-mortem) from our RSS Feed. And in it he makes an observation about a strange rule:

> Weird rule thing. You recover half your level in hit dice during a
>   long rest, which means level 1 characters never recover hit dice.

That didn't make sense to me, and so I double checked the long rest rule and it reads:

> At the end of a long rest, a character regains all lost it points.
>   The  character also regains spent Hit Dice, up to a number of dice
>   equal to half of the character’s total number of them. For example, if
>   a  character has eight Hit Dice, he or she can regain four spent Hit
>   Dice upon finishing a long rest.

And of course the rules state that in general you always round down.

Am I missing something? Is there a good explanation for why at first level you can't recover hitdice?

Comment: I thought that things related to healing always rounded up, or was I misinterpreting the rule?

Comment: @AveRoma You always round down.

Comment: Thank you. I'm about to run a 5e campaign (I think, schedules being what they are and all), and this will prove useful.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

A few folks have mentioned to me that Mike Mearls has stated elsewhere that it's an oversight in the text, and the intent is that a level 1 character should recover 1 hit die. Seems likely errata-fodder.

> **@MrMattFree :** Hit dice question! Basic rules say you get half your HD back at a long rest but doesn't say round up. What does a 1st lvl do?
>
> **@mikemearls :** should be minimum 1.

The rules for long rests were [later updated](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/Errata_PH.pdf) to say that the minimum is 1 hit die.

> The character also regains spent Hit Dice, up to a number of dice equal to half of the character’s total number of them (minimum of one die). (PBRv0.2 p.67, PHB5e p.186)

Comment: The starter kit has the same issue where it is not clear if a 1st level character regains any hit dice