# Can level 1 characters use Healing Surges since they only have 1 Hit Die?

Tags: dnd-5e, healing, optional-rules

In the DMG there is the optional rule on pg.266-267 for healing surges. Part of the text says

> As an action, a character can use a healing surge and spend up to half
>   his or her Hit Dice.

So what would you do as a DM for level 1 characters - because they only have 1 hit dice?

Seems to me this would be more needed at level 1 than any other level - but with the round down rules 1/2 == 0.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### They can't, but it's probably a mistake

You're correct that a level 1 character has 1 hit die and since Healing Surge lets them use half, rounded down, it doesn't do anything for them.

That said, [there was an identical issue](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44722/at-level-one-can-you-really-never-recover-hit-dice) with recovering hit dice that was corrected once it was pointed out. I expect that the intent is for there to be a minimum of 1 hit die for healing surge as well.

Comment: In 3.5 many effects have a minimum of 1. Rolling d6-1 is always 1 or more, even if you roll the 1. I do not know if 5e uses the same rule.

Comment: @Me_Maikey For damage, at least, there is no minimum in 5e. So sayth Jeremy Crawford https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/609026410703822848

Comment: I agree, I feel the intent was that every level can healing surge, so while the RAW is not to allow it I am going to accept that the intent was indeed for all to have the chance

Comment: Oddly enough, this has not been addressed in the DMG errata http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/DMG_Errata.pdf

Answer (score 3):

A first level character has 1/2=0 hit dice to spend and cannot benefit from Healing Surge.

Comment: I would add the quote from phb reference rounding down to further reinforce this dale.