# What mechanical options do player characters have to desecrate a surface?

Tags: dnd-5e

Following up on:

- [What are the mechanical consequences that arise for a PC with the undead creature type?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/136010/42805)
- [How might this homebrew undead hybrid character type unbalance combat compared to non-undead creatures?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/144855/42805)
- [Does the Detect Evil and Good spell let the player know what kind of ground (consecrated or desecrated) they have found?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/135359/42805)

### Long story short

Due to a series of deadly and unholy events two PCS at my table are creatures that are both undead and humanoid. As part of their undead nature, they carry certain mechanical flaws and benefits, such as:

> **Desecration.** Advantage on ability checks, saves and attack rolls while standing on a desecrated surface.

(This is homebrew, including the whole becoming undead)

The party doesn't yet know about *this* mechanic, but is likely to soon find out. When they do, it's very likely they will attempt to *create* desecrated surfaces, instead of just finding them.

**Party composition (level 12):** minotaur paladin of conquest, animated armor eldritch knight/abjurer, undead tabaxi beast conclave ranger/assassin/warlock of the undying, undead high elf mastermind, tiefling pact of the tome warlock.

### Question

**What mechanical options do player characters have to desecrate a surface?**

*Mechanical options* include spells, (magic) items, class features, etc.
*Surface* can refer to the floor/ground, or a big object on which someone could stand (such as a table or chair). For now I'm only interested in the options by RAW, and possibly from any of the UA.

---

*Note 1. If you have an interesting homebrew option that fits my search, only share that if it is tested by your table.*

*Note 2. This question is **not** about whether this homebrew mechanic of their creature type is balanced or a good idea in general.*